# how do I use terminal escape codes with java?

Tags: java

This C code could clear screen in Unix-like systems (posix terminals)

```
printf ("\e [1;1H\e[2J");
```

while Java code causes errors

```
system.out.println ("\e [1;1H\e[2J");
```

how do I make it work?

Comment: In a string, you need to escape the backslash characters, so "\\e [1;1H\\e[23".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal solution for doing this, as not all consoles are built the same depending on their respective environment.

Now if you're on a UNIX-based environment, chances are you could try the following code:

```
static void clearConsole() {   
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");   
    System.out.flush();   
}
```

The first line uses ANSI escape sequences to control the standard output. You can learn more about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences).
The `System.out.flush()` call on the second line causes any leftover characters which are holding up in a stream to be sent .

But keep in mind that this is an environment-dependent solution. It is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

`\e` is not really standard. You should use other ways to write the escape character, such as entering its octal code (`\033`).